# Contact form 7 - How to send MMS message in mobile

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, mms

Is it possible to send MMS message in mobile using contact form 7 ??

[image]

I have set above configuration in **Mail 2**.I want to send image so I set it like **number@mms.att.net** but it's not working. Is there any way I can send MMS message using Contact Form 7 ??

Comment: You can use this plugin for sending SMS from Contact Form 7 - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sms/.

Comment: I want to send MMS for  **AT&T MOBILE CARRIER**

Comment: Unfortunately, no plugin there supporting MMS from Contact Form 7.

Comment: Can we have alternate way for the same ?? Using Contact form 7 only ..

Comment: You can use `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook to get the posted data and then add your MMS script.